# Creating a list column returns undesired result

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I am in need of creating a custom column for a SharePoint list. I need to add custom metadata to the files I will be saving under that list. I followed the instructions in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-post-columns?view=graph-rest-1.0); Nonetheless, I'm getting an unexpected result when it comes to a certain property specifically.

My intention is to create a Multiple lines text column. This is the body I am sending on the PATCH request:

```
{
    "columnGroup": "Custom Columns",
    "description": "Custom app metadata",
    "displayName": "App Data",
    "enforceUniqueValues": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "indexed": false,
    "name": "AppData",
    "readOnly": false,
    "required": false,
    "text": {
        "allowMultipleLines": true,
        "appendChangesToExistingText": false,
        "linesForEditing": 6,
        "textType": "plain"
    }
}
```

However, the response I am getting back is this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.list)('777xxx77-x77x-7xx7-xx77-7x7x7x7x7x')/columns/$entity",
    "columnGroup": "Custom Columns",
    "description": "Custom app metadata",
    "displayName": "App Data",
    "enforceUniqueValues": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "id": "777xxx77-x77x-7xx7-xx77-7x7x7x7x7x", //replaced original with dummy id
    "indexed": false,
    "name": "AppData",
    "readOnly": false,
    "required": false,
    "text": {
        "allowMultipleLines": true,
        "appendChangesToExistingText": true,
        "linesForEditing": 6,
        "textType": "plain"
    }
}
```

The key point here is that the property **appendChangesToExistingText**, which is set to **false** in the request body, is returned as **true** in the response body.

That little thing is driving me nuts. The reason for that is that I get this "View Entries" thing in the sharepoint column. I have done some research an apparently, it is caused by that property set to TRUE.

[image]

My question is.... Why is not the API working as expected? Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug in the API? Is it not ready for production yet? Can anyone shed some light please?

Comment: I'm getting this issue both with PATCH requests on existing columns and also POST requests when creating new columns. Always sending `"appendChangesToExistingText": false` but getting back `true`. Infuriatingly confusing! You're correct that this is what's causing the page to show "View Entries" but I can't seem to get it to behave.

Answer (score 1):

When the text column has `allowMultipleLines` set to `true`, `appendChangesToExistingText` is either `true` for versioned fields, **or omitted**. If present, it will create a versioned text field. Why? ‍♂️

When creating or modifying a column, I therefore needed to precede the API call with code to remove the property if set to `false`:

```
try:
    if field_props['text']['appendChangesToExistingText] == False:
        del field_props['text']['appendChangesToExistingText]
except:
    pass
```

---

Source: I asked ChatGPT for this, out of sheer desperation. It told me that "The documentation explains that this property can only be set to "true" or omitted for multi-line text columns in SharePoint Online" but I have been unable to locate this "documentation".